# make diagonal background in flutter

Tags: flutter

I want to make a background like this picture .please help me
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a `ClipPath` widget, with a custom clipper argument that will represent your diagonal cut in the white or red part of your background

You can get heavily inspired by the code of the diagonal package on pub.dev or use the dependency.

https://github.com/figengungor/diagonal/blob/master/lib/diagonal.dart

Answer (score 0):

You need a stack. As first element you use a container with a clippath (see @BLKKKBVSIK answer) or if you don't want to program this yourself, then you can use e.g.

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_custom_clippers

and use the DiagonalPathClipper. Then you do the rest of the elements on your stack.

Answer (score 0):

use `ClipPath`
You can achieve the desired result by extending `CustomClipper<Path>`.

```
class DiagonalClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    final path = Path();
    path.lineTo(0.0, size.height * 0.65);
    path.lineTo(size.width, size.height);
    path.lineTo(size.width, 0.0);
    path.close();
    return path;
  }
  @override
  bool shouldReclip(DiagonalClipper oldClipper) => false;
}
```

**UI code**

```
ClipPath(
    clipper: DiagonalClipper(),
    child: Container(
        height: boxHeight,
        child: ...,
    ),
 ),
```